# VBA SQL Aggregate Function Issue

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, aggregate-functions

I'm quite new to vba and sql and I am having a little trouble importing some data from my database query into excel via vba.

I have the following sql generating a query in Access which displays the query results no problem.

```
SELECT  tblSection.Section_Name, 
        IIf(Sum(qry_Total_Assigned_MB.[Total Assigned Main Book]) Is Null,0,
            Sum(qry_Total_Assigned_MB.[Total Assigned Main Book])) As [Total MB Assigned], 
        IIf(Sum([qry_Total_Shoot_Complete_MB].[Total MB Product Shoot Complete]) Is Null,0,
            Sum([qry_Total_Shoot_Complete_MB].[Total MB Product Shoot Complete])) As [Total MB Product Shoot Complete], 
        IIf(Sum(qry_Total_Assigned_MidB.[Total Assigned Mid Book]) Is Null,0,
            Sum(qry_Total_Assigned_MidB.[Total Assigned Mid Book])) As [Total MidB Assigned], 
        IIf(Sum([qry_Total_Shoot_Complete_MidB].[Total MidB Product Shoot Complete]) Is Null,0,
            Sum([qry_Total_Shoot_Complete_MidB].[Total MidB Product Shoot Complete])) As [Total MidB Product Shoot Complete], 
        IIf(Sum([qry_Total_Assigned_ECA].[Total Assigned ECA]) Is Null,0,
            Sum([qry_Total_Assigned_ECA].[Total Assigned ECA])) As [Total ECA Assigned], 
        IIf(Sum([qry_Total_Assigned_ECOMM].[Total Assigned ECOMM]) Is Null,0,
            Sum([qry_Total_Assigned_ECOMM].[Total Assigned ECOMM])) As [Total ECOMM Assigned], 
        IIf(Sum([qry_Total_Assigned_Marketing].[Total Assigned Marketing]) Is Null,0,
            Sum([qry_Total_Assigned_Marketing].[Total Assigned Marketing])) As [Total Marketing Assigned], 
        IIf([Total MB Assigned]=0,"0",IIf([Total MB Product Shoot Complete]=0,"0",
            ([Total MB Product Shoot Complete])/([Total MB Assigned]))) As [Percentage MB Complete] 

FROM    ((((((tblSection 
        LEFT JOIN qry_Total_Assigned_MB
            ON tblSection.Section_Name = qry_Total_Assigned_MB.Section_Name) 
        LEFT JOIN qry_Total_Assigned_MidB 
            ON tblSection.Section_Name = qry_Total_Assigned_MidB.Section_Name) 
        LEFT JOIN qry_Total_Assigned_ECA 
            ON tblSection.Section_Name = qry_Total_Assigned_ECA.Section_Name) 
        LEFT JOIN qry_Total_Assigned_ECOMM 
            ON tblSection.Section_Name = qry_Total_Assigned_ECOMM.Section_Name) 
        LEFT JOIN qry_Total_Assigned_Marketing 
            ON tblSection.Section_Name = qry_Total_Assigned_Marketing.Section_Name) 
        LEFT JOIN qry_Total_Shoot_Complete_MB 
            ON tblSection.Section_Name = qry_Total_Shoot_Complete_MB.Section_Name) 
        LEFT JOIN qry_Total_Shoot_Complete_MidB 
            ON tblSection.Section_Name = qry_Total_Shoot_Complete_MidB.Section_Name 
GROUP BY tblSection.Section_Name;
```

I am then trying to use vba to pull a records data from the query generated using the below sql statement via vba into excel:

```
SELECT [Total MB Assigned] 
FROM qry_MI_Total_Assigned 
WHERE [Section_Name] = '" & fnSection_Name & "' 
GROUP BY [Section_Name];
```

When running the above code I get the following error:

> You tired to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'IIf(IIf(Is Null,0,)=0,"0", IIf([Total MB Product Shoot Complete]=0, "0",[Total MB Product Shoot Complete]/[Total MB Assigned]))' as part of an aggregate function."

If anyone can point me in the right direction, or if I am doing this completely wrong I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is fairly self explanatory, in the following query:

```
SELECT [Total MB Assigned] 
FROM qry_MI_Total_Assigned 
WHERE [Section_Name] = '" & fnSection_Name & "' 
GROUP BY [Section_Name];
```

You have `[Total MB Assigned]` in the select list, but not in an aggregate function or part of the group by. Since `qry_MI_Total_Assigned` is a stored query the error message is just giving you the full definition of this column.

Since the query `qry_MI_Total_Assigned` already groups by `[Section_Name]` I think your `GROUP BY` is redundant, and theat the following will work as you are expecting

```
SELECT [Total MB Assigned] 
FROM qry_MI_Total_Assigned 
WHERE [Section_Name] = '" & fnSection_Name & "'
```